# Set contact group display option programmatically

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'm trying to set the display option of a account to visible programmatically but having no luck so far. At the moment I'm having to go into my contacts, selecting options, clicking on display options and then manually making them visible.

No doubt if i release my app like this i will get many complaints about contacts not showing up etc...

Any help would be much apreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got two ways of doing it. One by creating a entry in Groups table and another in Settings. Can you try below and check?.

```
        cv.put(ContactsContract.Settings.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.Settings.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountYype);
        cv.put(ContactsContract.Settings.UNGROUPED_VISIBLE, 1);
        getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Settings.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a entry into group table(Groups.CONTENT_URI) with your account name and set visibility ( Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE) to true (1).

Comment: Okay, are you able to give me some example code on how to do this please?

Comment: Actualy, I've done it now, but it isn't workign correctly, do i have to specify what 'group' to be visible?